# XML Serializing a List<Class>

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having issues deserializing XML which I can't quite figure out. Mainly, I'm trying to avoid having to nest classes when they're inside a list but not succeeding. For example:

```
[XmlRoot]
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlElement("Bar")]
    public BarElement Bar = new BarElement();

    public class BarElement
    {
        [XmlElement("MoreBars")]
        public List<MoreElement> MoreBars = new List<MoreElement>();
    }

    [XmlRoot("More")]
    [Serializable]
    public class MoreElement
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Attribute")]
        public string Attribute { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Corresponds to:

```
<Foo>
    <Bar>
        <MoreBars>
            <More Attribute=""></More>
            <More Attribute=""></More>
            <More Attribute=""></More>
            <More Attribute=""></More>
        </MoreBars>
    </Bar>
</Foo>
```

This almost works... but not quite. By adding XmlRoot to MoreElement, I'm trying to avoid the necessity of having to create a new class named "MoreBarsElement" that contains only a List of MoreElements, since it's already quite a chore to access "Foo.Bar.MoreBars.Value". Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question - looks like I needed

```
[XmlArray("MoreBars"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(MoreElement), ElementName = "More")]
```

On the array item declaration. It works now, hurray!

Comment: Make sure you mark this as the answer for others (click the checkmark below the voting).